# data trunction : incorrect data value : 'yyyy MMM d' for column 'date_acd' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql

Hello i have this error in my program and i can't found the solution .This is my code follow me:

```
private void bt2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
try{

        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"confirmer la modification ","modification sur un departement",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        st.execute("Update departement set code_departement = '"+txtcode.getText()+"',nom_departement = '"+txtnom.getText()
                +"',date_acd = '"+jdat.getDateFormatString()+"' where code_departement = "+txtcode.getText());
        AfficherDepartement();
        }

    }   catch(Exception e)  {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"erreur de modifier le departement !!!!\n"+e.getMessage());
            System.err.println(e);}
```

Comment: I see nothing in this code snippet related to MySQL, JDBC, Hibernate, or anything related to the error message.

Comment: You should learn about prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

Format the date like **'yyyy-MM-dd'**, before set to the query.
You can use for it

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat
```

class.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Comment: That's what the OP is trying to do.  What's (probably) going wrong in their code?  What (specifically) needs to be changed?  Where does your fix fit in?  There's also a very big risk in the OP's current code you should warn about.